# jaxrs configuring multiple jaxrs:server tags with different beans

Tags: jax-rs

This problem is related to JAX-RS configuration.

I configured JAX-RS for a single class.  The configuration worked fine.

```
@Path(/bean1/)
@Produces("application/xml")
public class class1 {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path(/m1)
    public String method1(JAXBElement<String> request) {
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path(/m2)
    public String method2(JAXBElement<String> request) {
    }
}
```

Below is jaxrs:server tag

```
<jaxrs:server id="bean1" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="class1" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I could call through Apache Jersey client with URL "/bean1/m1"

---

Now, I wanted to configure another class with JAX-RS.  Hence, I added configuration as below

```
@Path(/bean2/)
@Produces("application/xml")
public class class2 {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path(/m3)
    public String method3(JAXBElement<String> request) {
    }
}
```

I added another jaxrs:server tag and specified address.  The effective configuration is

```
<jaxrs:server id="bean1" address="/bean1">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="class1" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
<jaxrs:server id="bean2" address="/bean2">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="class2" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I again tried to call web service with URL "/bean1/m1".

However, I received an error No root resource matching request path /m1 has been found.

Requesting help.

Comment: Apache Jersey? Don't you mean Apache CXF or Sun/Oracle Jersey?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at your configuration you now have a mapping that maps to:

```
/bean1/bean1/m1

/bean2/bean2/m3
```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="server" address="/">
  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="class1" />
    <ref bean="class2" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
  </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

You can just define 2 servicebeans for the same server if you want. That should give you what you want.